# Cant retrieve JSONArray from IP server but I can from normal server?

Tags: android, json, httpclient

Im migrating a service from a normal domain DNS server to a IP only server and this provides a json service for my app, the problem is I cant retrieve the JSONArray with the following code in the new URL:

```
 protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                String reponse;

                try{
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                    HttpResponse responce = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = responce.getEntity();
                    reponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    return new JSONArray(reponse);
                    //With the oldURL I printed the JSON as a string and everithing OK but the new URL returns a null string of JSON
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }


                return null;
            }

String newurlexample = "http://111.22.333.44:1234/FOLD/blablabla";

String oldurl = "https:/example.com/FOLD/file.json";
```

And I get the following LOG:

```
    07-13 17:47:02.142: W/System.err(18824): org.json.JSONException: Value Method of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
07-13 17:47:02.145: W/System.err(18824):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
07-13 17:47:02.145: W/System.err(18824):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
07-13 17:47:02.146: W/System.err(18824):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
07-13 17:47:02.146: W/System.err(18824):    at com.karlol.***.Doctor_Fragment$GetData.doInBackground(Doctor_Fragment.java:171)
07-13 17:47:02.146: W/System.err(18824):    at com.karlol.***.Doctor_Fragment$GetData.doInBackground(Doctor_Fragment.java:1)
07-13 17:47:02.147: W/System.err(18824):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-13 17:47:02.147: W/System.err(18824):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-13 17:47:02.147: W/System.err(18824):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-13 17:47:02.147: W/System.err(18824):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
```

Comment: My first response is: Why aren't you using [Volley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo)?

Comment: Make sure you can access your IP URL and it returns valid JSON. Also print "reponse" variable to see what the server returns

Comment: the URL returns a valid JSON and "reponse" returns: `Method[POST]Not Allowed, Please Make sure the REST MEthod [POST] for resource [my new address] is available in the other side!`

Comment: What is the actual output that you are getting back? Add a print out of the response. Because it sounds like you are forcing a string into a json array...

Comment: Are you putting JSON to the server or retrieving file.json FROM the server? If it is the latter, I'd imagine you'd want a GET operation. Your web server is telling you it doesn't know or won't permit a POST at the `blahblah` location.

In either case, try replacing `blahblah` with `file.json`.

Comment: The new adress actually is not a JSON file (file.json) its just an address (file, without extension)

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: What you can do is test your web service in any Rest Client.. Postman in chrome and RESTClient in firefox.. Install any of these on your relevant browser and test the response you are getting from live IP.. And show the response you are getting from local and live url..

Answer (score 2):

From the title of your question I can notice that there is something wrong between the URL you were using and the new ip .. first you need to make sure your new web-service provide the same result as the old one ..
any way you can try to retrieve your data using this :

```
try{
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
       HttpResponse responce = httpclient.execute(httppost);
       HttpEntity httpEntity = responce.getEntity();
       is = httpEntity.getContent();
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            is));

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String line = null;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
        reponse = sb.toString();


       return new JSONArray(reponse);
       //With the oldURL I printed the JSON as a string and everithing OK but the new URL returns a null string of JSON

       }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();

}
```

**EDIT:**

If you use shared hosting server.. it is not uncommon to have multiple web sites on the same IP, distinguished only by the site name (so-called virtual hosting). What you are doing will only work for the case where there is a single site on a given IP.

**EDIT 2**

You need to test your webservice using a RESTful plugin (chrome or firefox) i.e., [Advanced rest client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)

Comment: Sorry but "is" of what type is that variable? InputStream?

Comment: `static InputStream is = null;`

Comment: your webservice is not allowing POST requests ! can you give me an example of what you are sending ? you need to test your webservice using RESTful plugins ...

Comment: you don't have any problem from android side, you need to verify the restful service..

Answer (score 2):

We have the same problem before try to use this. change the one inside your try and catch with this. hope it helps.

```
      FileCache filecache;


String result="";
                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                String finalurl="http://111.22.333.44:1234/FOLD/blablabla";
                filecache = new FileCache(context);
                File f = filecache.getFile(finalurl);
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(finalurl);
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                    conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
                    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
                    FileReader isr = new FileReader(f);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                    is.close();
                    os.close();
                    conn.disconnect();
                    return new JSONArray(result);
                }catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e("Error", ex+"can't access" + finalurl + result);
                }
```

FileCache.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import java.io.File;

    /**
     * Created by cristiana214 on 1/26/2015.
     */
    public class FileCache {
        private File cacheDir;
        public FileCache(Context context) {
            // Find the dir to save cached images
            if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                    android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                cacheDir = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(),"folder/i");
            } else
                cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
            if (!cacheDir.exists())
                cacheDir.mkdirs();
        }

        public File getFile(String url) {
            String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
            File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
            return f;
        }
        public void clear() {
            File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
            if (files == null)
                return;
            for (File f : files)
                f.delete();
        }
    }
```

Utils.java

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * Created by cristiana214 on 1/26/2015.
 */
public class Utils  {
    public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os){
        final int buffer_size=1024*10;
        try{
            byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
            for(;;){
                int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
                if(count==-1)
                    break;
                os.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

Comment: @Karlo A. López please comment if you  solved your issues already.

Answer (score 2):

According to your error code

```
org.json.JSONException: Value Method of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

you are trying to convert a String to JSONArray.
there is also a pointer to doInBackground task, line 171 so you should definitely check this line. 
I guess the problem is around these lines:

```
reponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
return new JSONArray(reponse);
```

Answer (score 2):

If this helps someone, I had to change the request to a GET instead of POST and this code worked perfectly, although I couldnt get to work the POST request.

```
    try {
                    URL obj = new URL("http://anIPaddress/REST/Folder/Consult?Operation=AnOperation");
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
//con default method is GET
                    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                    Log.v("Lolo", "\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + con.getURL());
                    Log.v("Lolo", "RESPONSE CODE : " + responseCode);
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();

                    return new JSONArray(response.toString());
    }
```

Thanks a lot for your answers and your help.

Answer (score 1):

Check this line in your log message :

> W/System.err(18824): org.json.JSONException: Value Method of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

You are getting this exception because the response from server you are receiving is not formatted as JSON format. So when you try to convert the response string to JSONArray its throwing the above JSONException.

Now the solution for your problem is :  you need to make sure that the response is formatted as correct JSON format. And log your response before parsing to JSON by which you can check response is correct or not.

Hope this helps you :)
Thanks

Comment: The info was not being in JSON format cause it was not receiving any info! The problem was the request.